# c# const in jQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code in javascript:

```
 var catId = $.getURLParam("category");
```

In my asp.net and c# code for "category" query string i use a public const:

```
public const string CATEGORY = "category";
```

so if i want to change the query string parameter to be "categoryTest" i only change this const and all the code is updated.

Now the question is: how can i do something similar for the javascript i have in the same application (so i want to use the same constant)?

I mean i want something like this:

```
var catId = $.getURLParam(CQueryStringParameters.CATEGORY);
```

but because there are none asp.net tags, my const is not interpreted...

Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a global variable in your aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var categoryParam = '<%= CQueryStringParameters.CATEGORY %>';
</script>
```

And then use this global variable in your javascript file:

```
var catId = $.getURLParam(categoryParam);
```